# Given this sequence, find the limit

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

[image]

In the second question, beyond this step I am stuck.
[image]

Any hints??

Comment: Express all elements of $x_n$ using only $\theta_0$

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired. Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources.

Ref: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/20334/290189

Answer (score 0):

Hint : $\prod_{k=1}^n \cos {2^k \theta}$ = $\dfrac 1{2^n}\dfrac {\sin 2^{n+1}\theta}{\sin \theta}$

If you are still unable to solve, drop a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_0=\cos\alpha_0$ and we get the answer: $\arccos{x_0}$